# How to validate google access token inside of .net backend

Tags: c#, google-oauth

Inside my frontend react app I get a token from google like this, using `@react-oauth/google` package

```
const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (response) =>
      requestExternalLogin("google", response.access_token),
    flow: "implicit",
  });
```

token response object example:

```
access_token: "ya29.a0AX9GBdUordgkAamV_nnKl3NEF6..."
authuser: "0"
expires_in: 3599
hd: "visma.com"
prompt: "none"
scope: "email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
token_type: "Bearer"
```

I then pass that token to my .net backend and try to validate it like this:

```
var settings = new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings()
{
    Audience = new List<string>() { _googleConfig.GetSection("clientId").Value }
};

var payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(googleToken, settings);
```

but I keep getting an exception that says `{"JWT must consist of Header, Payload, and Signature"}`

Access token that I get from google should be a valid JWT that canbe used to get information from google's apis. Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Your react project shouldn't call google api directly only through your .net backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google access tokens are not JWT's that can be validated in that manner.  Try puting it in [Jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) you will get the same error.

The only way to validate an google access token would be to use it with an api call if its not valid google will return an error.

You should be able to validate a refresh token though, and possibly an id token.

Comment: As much as I didn't want to hear this kind of answer, you're right. I ended up using the new google api directly to get the id token, because all the libraries were using the old one and that soon will be deprecated.

Comment: Which libraries are you using that are being deprecated?

Comment: I tried react-google-login which was using the old api. And I tried @react-oauth/google, which uses the new gsi api, but I couldn't figure out how to get idToken using that.

Comment: check out my answer if you're interested in how I implemented this without a package.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the selected answer, I was using the wrong kind of token. I needed id token, but the libraries either did not provide this token, or were using the old api. To use google's apis directly I ended up running this kind of setup:

useGoogleLogin hook

```
export function useGoogleLogin(
  btnRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
  loginCallback: (idToken: string) => void
) {
  const scriptCallback = () => {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
      callback: (response) => loginCallback(response.credential),
    })

    google.accounts.id.renderButton(btnRef.current as HTMLElement, {
      theme: 'outline',
      size: 'large',
      type: 'standard',
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'
    const scriptId = 'gsi-client'

    loadScript(src, scriptId, scriptCallback)
  }, [])
}
```

loadScript function

```
const loadScript = (src: string, id: string, onload: () => void = () => {}) => {
  const existingScript = document.getElementById(id)

  if (existingScript != null) return

  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.id = id
  script.src = src
  script.defer = true
  script.async = true
  script.onload = onload

  document.head.appendChild(script)
}

export default loadScript
```

And then just use it in your component like this:

```
const divRef = useRef(null)

useGoogleLogin(divRef, (idToken: string) => {
  //callback when user clicks the button
  //use this callback to send idToken to your backend or do something else
})

return <div ref={divRef} /> //your google login button
```

You also need to install @types/google.accounts, if you're running typescript